# Hangfire with mysql incorrect syntax near 'rank from hangfireSet

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire with MySql database in Asp.Net MVC application.

```
Hangfire.Core v1.7.3.0
Hangfire.MySql v1.0.0.0
MySql.Data v8.0.16.0
MySqlConnector v0.62.0.0
```

The hangfire dashboard page shows fine.i.e, `http://website.com/hangfire`

But recurring jobs page gives error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank
>      from `hangfireSet`,
>              (select @rownum := 0) r
>          wh' at line 3

**Stack trace:**

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank
        from `hangfireSet`,
            (select @rownum := 0) r 
        wh' at line 3]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +47
   MySqlConnector.Core.<ReadResultSetHeaderAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +343

[MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank
        from `hangfireSet`,
            (select @rownum := 0) r 
        wh' at line 3]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() +407
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.<CreateAsync>d__95.MoveNext() +834
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +26
   MySqlConnector.Core.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1855
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +74
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd, Boolean wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior) +60
   Dapper.<QueryImpl>d__138`1.MoveNext() +292
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +186
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +61
   Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) +379
   Hangfire.MySql.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<GetRangeFromSet>b__0(MySqlConnection connection) +120
   Hangfire.MySql.MySqlStorage.UseConnection(Func`2 func) +56
   Hangfire.MySql.MySqlStorageConnection.GetRangeFromSet(String key, Int32 startingFrom, Int32 endingAt) +100
   Hangfire.Storage.StorageConnectionExtensions.GetRecurringJobs(JobStorageConnection connection, Int32 startingFrom, Int32 endingAt) +29
   Hangfire.Dashboard.Pages.RecurringJobsPage.Execute() +413
   Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPage.TransformText(String body) +26
   Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPage.ToString() +7
   Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPageDispatcher.Dispatch(DashboardContext context) +65
   Hangfire.Dashboard.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<UseHangfireDashboard>b__1(IDictionary`2 env) +430
   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +273
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +556
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +556
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +638
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +638
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +180
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +429
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

How can I resolve this error and can see recurring jobs?

Comment: Show full problematic query text. PS. Looks like using reserved word `rank` as an subquery alias without quoting.

Comment: Have you tried removing the job and recreating it? Does that resolve the issue?